# Software to route a headset connected to a Windows PC to Mac Audio

Tags: windows, osx, audio

I have a USB headset that I use as my microphone. However, because it is a USB-A headset, it does not work with my Macbook.

Is there any software that can route my Windows Input to my Mac input? That is, have the headphones plugged into my Windows PC and somehow route it to my Mac input.

Comment: Why not use a USB adapter?